# Use Multiple Patterns in Vimgrep in Key Mapping

Tags: vim, vimgrep

In my vimrc I had a mapping to find all line with TODO in them and put them in the quickfix window:

```
 nnoremap <leader>f :vimgrep /TODO/j % \| :cw<CR>
```

I now want to add the alternative pattern FIXME in the same way. So I tried

```
 nnoremap <leader>f :vimgrep /TODO\|FIXME/j % \| :cw<CR>
```

and

```
nnoremap <leader>f :vimgrep /TODO<bar>FIXME/j % \| :cw<CR>
```

but neither return any results.

```
 vimgrep /TODO|FIXME/j %
```

works at the : prompt when typed manually. So far my work-around is this:

```
function! FindFixme()
    vimgrep /TODO\|FIXME/j %
    cw
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>f :call FindFixme()<CR>
```

But I don't really understand why I can't get it to work as a single map command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The regular expression item for *alternation* is `\|`, and you indeed need to escape a `|` so that it doesn't end the mapping command. Taken together, you need *two* backslashes: one for escaping and one to remain for the item:

```
nnoremap <leader>f :vimgrep /TODO\\|FIXME/j % \| :cw<CR>
```

But I would prefer the `<Bar>` notation, maybe even combined with `<Bslash>`:

```
nnoremap <leader>f :vimgrep /TODO<Bslash><Bar>FIXME/j % <Bar> :cw<CR>
```

You can further shorten this to:

```
nnoremap <leader>f :vimgrep /TODO<Bslash><Bar>FIXME/j %<Bar>cw<CR>
```